# How to pull unique emojis from a character vector in R?

Tags: r, emoji

Let's say I have a character vector named **sampleData** containing emojis

```
sampleData <- c('', '❤️','❤️')
```

How would I pull each unique emojis from this vector so that the end result only contains ❤️?

I tried the following with no luck.

```
sampleData <- stri_paste(sampleData, collapse = ' ')
unique(sampleData)
```

Comment: in the desired output:  is missing!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution to your problem but it is quite complex as emojis are a special format/encoding and there can be many customs once. The main problem to solve was to get a list/df of as many emojis as possible and work from there. Lucky for us there is such package for R: https://github.com/Rkabacoff/emoji2text
This solution is not perfect but it does the job you are looking for - you have to be aware, that due to the large range of emojis and possible customs you might have to clean or increase the list/df of registred emojis to your need (you will see in a second what I mean)

```
#remotes::install_github("Rkabacoff/emoji2text")
library(emoji2text)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)


x <- emoji2text::emoji_to_text(sampleData, accents=TRUE) %>% # convert emojis to readable text inbetween  parenthesis
  dplyr::as_tibble() %>% # convert this to a tibble
  dplyr::mutate(SPLIT_EMOJIS = stringr::str_split(value, "\\)")) %>% # split in nested rows by the closing brackets
  tidyr::unnest(SPLIT_EMOJIS) %>% # unnest the nested rows
  dplyr::filter(nchar(SPLIT_EMOJIS) > 0) %>% # get rid of "" lines
  dplyr::mutate(SPLIT_EMOJIS = paste0(SPLIT_EMOJIS, ")")) %>% # put the closing braket back on
  dplyr::distinct(SPLIT_EMOJIS) %>% # get the unique emojis
  dplyr::inner_join(emoji2text::Emojis, by = c("SPLIT_EMOJIS" = "words")) %>% # join to the df of emojis to get the encoding and convert written text to encoding that can be printed
  dplyr::group_by(SPLIT_EMOJIS) %>% # heart can be small and black or large and red (this is what I meant by possible need to customize the list/df of registred emojis - you could just drop the black heart in advance i.e.)
  dplyr::slice_head(n = 1) %>%  #so we get the first entry (large and red)
  dplyr::pull(emoji) # pull out only the colum of correctly encoded emojis

cat(x) # print them
    ❤️
```